# How to run chromium in puppeteer endlessly?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, chromium

I'm using puppeteer to print a web page and get pdf from it. The web page is quite heavy and it is taking 15 seconds to send the pdf response back. I'm using puppeteer in docker and for each request I'm launching the browser, visiting the page, printing it and getting the pdf back. 
What I want to do is, I want to make the chromium browser running in the background so that we can eliminate the time to launch browser.
I found the similar functionality in [browserless docs](https://docs.browserless.io/blog/2019/05/03/improving-puppeteer-performance.html#keep-chrome-running), but that is of royalty. Is there any way to get the same functionality in puppeteer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting Browsers in Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55096771/connecting-browsers-in-puppeteer)

Comment: I saw that answer previously and it is not related to what I wanted.

Comment: It is related, you want to launch a browser and then connect to that browser.